np.savetext()/pd.to_csv freezes virtual machine
I am using VS Code running a python script that is processing some data and saving it to a .csv-file. OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, running in VMware Workstation 16 Player (Host: Win 10). Unfortunately, on some saves it deadlocks my virtual machine. When I go to the details window in Windows Task Manager, it says the process is in a deadlock and shows me two threads of the VM waiting for each other.
        csvDF = csvDF[csvDF.index < i + 1]
        cutAt = path.find("temperatures_matched")
        path = path[:cutAt] + path2TestCSV[i]
        #csvDF.to_csv(path, index = False)
        np.savetxt(path, csvDF, fmt = '%s', delimiter= ',', header="minTemp,maxTemp,mean,matchedThermalArray")
        #time.sleep(0.5)
        #csvDF = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = csvColumns)

I already tested a delay after saving and switching from pd's to_csv() to np's savetext(), unfortunately without success.

What is the point of writing to a CSV and immediately reading into a dataframe?  You can import the numpy data directly into pandas and bypass the filesystem, right?

Just check you have enough memory. If you do not then the OS will try to fill every possible byte of memory and doing that can be extremely slow when the remaing amount of memory is limited. Alternatively, you can enable the OOM killer (so it will kill your application in this case because there is just not enough memory), or you can allocate some swap memory so your application can use it when there is no space left in RAM. Last but not least, you can increase the amount of memory allocated to your VM.

Besides, be aware that SSDs cells have a limited amount of writes. When they reach this limit, cells can become unusable and when most cells are unusable, the whole SSD is basically dead. Thus, writing large temporary data on your SSD can kill its life. This does not applies to HDDs (which are slow).

@TimRoberts Thats not what I do. The piece of code you're seeing is the one that gets executed every 120 iterations of a loop and is used to save the data as a csv.

I would expect that even if there were a deadlock present in Pandas/NumPy, that fact would only be apparent to the guest operating system. From the host operating system's perspective, a deadlock looks exactly the same as an idle VM. If the host operating system can detect a deadlock, I think that's more likely to be a bug in VMware Workstation than a bug in NumPy/Pandas.
